# How to close session with a Jquery UI tab click in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, session

I would like to know how to close session with a Jquery UI tab click in asp.net.

Actually I am working with upload Images and when user upload I am saving them under a folder with genrated random string value.

So I need to close the session with a tab click as I am having problem when the user refreshes and tries to upload  I'm getting error as the session is not clearing.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
            $(function () {
                var tempDir = randomString(8);
                document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value = tempDir;
                $("#uploader").plupload({
                    // General settings
                    runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
                    url: 'upload.aspx?xyz=' + tempDir,
                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                    max_file_count: 10,
                    chunk_size: '1mb',
                    unique_names: true
});
</script>
```

Here is the Jquery UI tab code:

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">
<li><a href="#tabs-2">
<li><a href="#tabs-3">
</ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
</div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
</div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
</div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have an **ajax** call to an **ASHX** file with ****IRequiresSessionState***  * Interface

and there you should use the session abandon.